# function return type with a different template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some C++ classes that all have the same template parameters

```
template <typename T, size_t i>
struct A {

};

template <typename T, size_t i>
struct B : A<T,i>{

};

template <typename T, size_t i>
struct C : A<T,i>{

};
```

and so on. I also have a series of methods that will work on any of these classes. However, the problem is in the return type. I would like this method to return an instance of the passed in class, with the integer decremented by one. For instance, if I just overload the function, that would look like this

```
template <typename T, size_t i>
A<T,i-1> func(const A<T,i> & a){

}

template <typename T, size_t i>
B<T,i-1> func(const B<T,i> & a){

}

template <typename T, size_t i>
C<T,i-1> func(const C<T,i> & a){

}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without overloading the function for each type? By that I mean... is it possible to replace these with a single templated function? The logic is identical for all of the functions.

I imagine that that would look something like

```
template <typename P, size_t i>
P<i-1> func( const P<i> & p ){

}
```

where `P` somehow captures the original type `A`, `B`, or `C`, as well as the inner type `T`.

Or, if you think CRTP is the way to go, then how would I structure that?

Comment: Would using simply return type deduction work in your case? Something like `template<class T> auto func(const T & p){ ... }`

Comment: I should have mentioned C++11

Comment: That would be easy for C++14, but the expression would be absolute hell in C++11

Comment: Then you may want to use a [template template argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) (a template argument that is itself a template).

Comment: Oh. Crap. Yeah I guess you are right. This is the prototypical example for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). These template parameters are themselves class templates. In the following example, `P` is a template parameter which expects a class template where that class template expects a type argument followed by a `size_t` argument (such as the class templates `A`, `B` or `C` you provided):

```
template<template<class, size_t> class P, class T, size_t i>
P<T, i - 1> my_func(const P<T, i> & my_P);

int main()
{
    A<int, 10> a;
    B<char, 3> b;
    C<double, 7> c;

    auto smaller_a = my_func(a); // is a A<int, 9>
    auto smaller_b = my_func(b); // is a B<char, 2>
    auto smaller_c = my_func(c); // is a C<double, 6>
}
```

Since you did not explain what your function should actually do, I've just provided the function declaration and left out the definition.

C++11 compilation demonstration : https://godbolt.org/g/zpXVEb

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally use the template template syntax.
In case template type definitions are recursive, I'd rather stick with the old school way:

```
template<typename T, int I>
struct A{
    using Other=A<T,I-1>;
};
template<typename P>
typename P::Other f(P);
```